# Mount docker volume to windows host

Tags: docker

I'm running docker for windows on my windows 10 machine (using hyper-v).

If I run the following commands:

```
docker volume create test
docker volume inspect test
```

I get:

```
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test/_data",
        "Name": "test",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

What I want to do is access the path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/test/_data` from my windows host machine. Is this possible? Maybe by using some other driver instead of `local`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it directly but you can mount and access it

```
docker run -v test:/vol/test -v ~/mydata:/vol/test2 alpine sh
```

Now you can access data from host in `/vol/test2` and from your volume in `/vol/test`. Copy anything across that you want